# how can i deep clone a list<T> in windows phone 8.1 without icloneable interface?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I want to deep clone a generic list but icloneable interface is not present  in windows phone 8.1 also binaryformatter class is also not present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 using System.IO;
 using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public static T DeepClone<T>(T obj)
{
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
      var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
      formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
      ms.Position = 0;
      return (T) formatter.Deserialize(ms);
  }
}
```

> - Your class MUST be marked as [Serializable] in order for this to    work.
> - Your source file must include the following code:

If you want clone all members and then refer this [Deep Copy of Object in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/deep-copy-of-object-in-C-Sharp/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own icloneable interface and define a function as follows:

```
 public interface IClonable<T>
 {
     T Clone();
 }

 public static T[] Clone<T>(this T[] origin) where T : IClonable<T>
 {
     return origin.Select(x => x.Clone()).ToArray();
 }
```